# AmazonS3Client ios sdk rename file in bucket

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How I can rename an existing file in my S3 bucket?

Answer (score 7):

You can't "rename" so to speak because the first few bytes of the key name are used for partitioning in your bucket, but what you can do is copy your object to give your copy another name. Something like this should do the trick:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY] autorelease];
[s3 copyObject:[[[S3CopyObjectRequest alloc] initWithSourceKey:MY_SOURCE_KEY sourceBucket:MY_BUCKET destinationKey:MY_DEST_KEY destinationBucket:MY_BUCKET] autorelease]];
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you'll want to then delete the existing object once you've confirmed the copy was successful.

Comment: Hello. I have crash like this: http://fatalweb.com/question/amazon-s3-copy-object-between-buckets-in-objective-c-11457499.html